# How to allow the user to draw with fingers and draw geometric figures on Android?

Tags: android

I have a class called DrawingView, where I have the method `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` wich responses to touch events. In this method, I'm allowing the user to draw in the free mode, the user just touch the screen and draw freedly.
But the problem is that I wanna allow the user to draw geometric figures, but it depends of the `onTouchEvent()` method too.

Here is the code of the method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Now, I wanna do something like this "[how to draw circle using Multitouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409476/how-to-draw-circle-using-multitouch)", but I can't change this method to do this.
And the drawings needs to stay in one View only.

There is some way to allow the user to draw thins like this? Because the two types of draw depends of the Motion Events.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the motions different enough that you can tell which one they're trying to do before doing the wrong one.  For example, if one behavior requires 2 fingers down and one requires one finger down, as soon as they start to move their first finger you can assume that they're doing the one finger behavior.

You don't really give us enough info to tell you how to do it for your case.  I can tell you that you'll need to change onTouchEvent to have a lot more logic in it-  trying to multiplex touch events ends up with very complex code inside it, usually you end up with some form of state machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw on `Bitmap` and than copy it to `Canvas` in `onDraw()` method. For this You can create class like this:

```
class GraphicsView extends View {
    private Bitmap buffCanvasBitmap = null;
    private Canvas buffCanvas = null;
    private float x = 0;
    private float y = 0;
    private float old_x = 0;
    private float old_y = 0;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    public GraphicsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setTextSize(20);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (buffCanvasBitmap == null) {
            buffCanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
            buffCanvas = new Canvas(buffCanvasBitmap);
            buffCanvas.drawColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(buffCanvasBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  {
        old_x = x;
        old_y = y;

        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
                buffCanvas.drawLine(old_x, old_y, x, y, paint);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

and than use it, for example, in your `Activity` by this way:

```
public GraphicsView gv;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    gv = new GraphicsView(this);
    setContentView(gv);
}
```

and You can draw directly on screen.